# How to prove that a given function is not a group homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-homomorphism

How to disprove a group homomorphism?

$\text{For } n \in \mathbb N, \pi \in S_n \text{is } S_n \rightarrow S_n, \sigma \mapsto \pi \sigma \text{ a group homomorphism}$.

I would like to prove that this is wrong.

$\phi(xx´) = \pi \sigma \pi \sigma ´ \text{ and } \phi(x) \phi(x´)= \pi \sigma \pi \sigma´\text{ so: } \phi(xx´)= \phi(x) \phi(x´)$. 
Well, I see that I have proved the opposite but I have no idea how I could do it the right way.

Comment: Why do you say that $\phi(xx´) = \pi \sigma \pi \sigma$?

Comment: To disprove something is a homomorphism,  you just need to find 2 elements (or one repeated) that the homomorphism property fails.  Try a specific $n,\pi$ and elements and see what happens

Comment: @ChrisCulter Should it be $\phi(xx´)= \pi \sigma \sigma ´$?

Comment: @jublikon Yep! Assuming, that is, that you're setting $x=\sigma$ and $x'=\sigma'$. It would be clearer to write just $\phi(xx')=\pi xx'$.

Comment: So now the question is, under what circumstances to we have $\pi\sigma\sigma'=\pi\sigma\pi\sigma'$?

Comment: @ChrisCulter if $\pi$ is the neutral element?

Comment: @jublikon Right! If $\pi$ is anything else, the identity fails, so your argument successfully proves that $\phi$ is not a homomorphism.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A group homomorphism will always take the identity to the identity, but the given function takes the identity to $\pi$.

Comment: Note that when the permutation is the identity, the function is indeed a homomorphism.